# Resize SSRS report column

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Is there a way to resize the column width in SSRS report i.e. to increase or decrease the column width once the report is rendered/generated ?

[image]

Comment: this cannot be done unfortunately

Comment: As @AlanSchofield said, I think it cannot be done, unless the report is opened using MS Excel.

Comment: Yep it cannot be done :(